# Plus-que-parfait du subjonctif après l'imparfait

Tags: concordance-des-temps

> Ils auraient voulu avoir été heureux.

Si je veux transformer cette phrase comme ça :

> Ils auraient voulu qu'ils eussent été heureux.

Est-ce que ma transformation serait correcte ?

Ma première phrase est tirée de cette phrase flaubertienne :

> Léon tout de suite envia le calme du tombeau, et même, un soir, il
>   avait écrit son testament en recommandant qu’on l’ensevelît dans ce
>   beau couvre-pied, à bandes de velours, qu’il tenait d’elle ; car c’est
>   ainsi [*qu’ils auraient voulu avoir été*](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Flaubert_-_Madame_Bovary,_Conard,_1910.djvu/349), l’un et l’autre se faisant un
>   idéal sur lequel ils ajustaient à présent leur vie passée.

Comment: Dans le second cas, le deuxième "ils" ne désigne pas les mêmes personnes que le premier "ils", en tout cas c'est mon premier ressenti, je ne sais pas si c'est la seule façon de comprendre la phrase. Pour ce qui est de la concordance des temps, j'aurais instinctivement utilisé "fussent heureux" ou "soient heureux" plutôt que "eussent été heureux".

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Selon les règles de la concordance des temps au subjonctif, quand le verbe dans la phrase principale est au conditionnel passé, le verbe dans la phrase secondaire doit être au subjonctif passé. C'est au moins ce que ma grammaire principale du français dit sur ce sujet.

Comment: La première phrase ne marche pas; Ils auraient voulu être heureux.

Comment: Je ne vois pas la phrase. Il vaut mieux mettre des phrase entière....

Answer (score 1):

C'est une belle phrase. Pourquoi vouloir la transformer ? Difficile de vous aider sans l savoir...
Votre 2ème phrase est correcte. Elle a peut-être l'inconvénient d'une possible ambiguïté notée dans la 1ère remarque. Le 2ème *ils* peut en effet s'appliquer à d'autres personnes que celles représentées par le 1er:

> Ils auraient voulu que leurs enfants eussent été heureux.

On peut aussi transformer en :

> Ils auraient voulu être heureux.

avec une légère perte de sens: dans la phrase initiale, le 2ème verbe est un passé dans le passé (comme dans la pauvre phrase "jeudi, ils auraient voulu avoir été heureux mercredi"); avec l'infinitif, non. Plus de notion de temps (infinitif infini...). Elle n'est pas tellement marquée non plus dans la phrase de Flaubert (en tout cas pas autant que dans ma phrase toute pourrie) mais la tournure nous fait bien ressentir que c'est... définitivement cramé !

Answer (score 0):

La concordance des temps est correcte.  Mais pas la transformation, qui prend une phrase deja alambiquée et la rend encore plus gravement illisible.